# how to make vscode report errors when running C programs

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, error-handling, gdb

I can compile, run and debug C programs without problems in Visual Studio Code, but when my program crashes at runtime, I only get this message:

[image]

When I debug the same program in Visual Studio 2017, I get a better message and I understand that the crashes is caused by access violation:

[image]

How can I make Visual Studio Code throw a similar message?

Comment: do you run the program in a debugger

Comment: i get the same result in the debug mode and in regular run

Comment: VS uses a different debugger, find out if gdb will break on an exception

Comment: create a [mre] complete with build commands